# Typescript : filter a table and return each mapped item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

i have a an array mapping action looking like this :

```
this.itemsList= res.map( ( x, index ) => {
                  x.id = x.code;
                  x.itemName = x.name;
                  return x;
              } );
```

I ve tried to optimize it like this **(2nd manner**):

```
      this.itemsList = res.map(({code: id, name: itemName}) => ({id, itemName}));
```

but i need to return each mapped element of the array (`return x`)

i wonder how to do it using my optimized manner (**2nd**)

**ideas ??**

Comment: `.map(...)` is not a filte function. Do you just want to receive a processed array with the attributes `id` and `itemName`?

Comment: You are implicitly returning the item by doing `=> ({ ... })` already so not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `...` spread operator to spread the remaining object properties into a value, and the use the spread operator again to spread those properties from the stored object back into the target object.

```
res.map(({ code: id, name: itemName, ...otherProps }) => ({
  id, itemName, ...otherProps,
}));
```

Note that this does remove the original `code` and `name` properties. If you still need those, you'll have to add them explicitly as well.

```
res.map(props => ({
  id: props.code,
  itemName: props.name,
  ...props,
}));
```

---

When you say `filter` I believe you are referring to the plucking of specific properties -- in this case using destructuring. This is different than the collection `filter` operation which removes elements from a collection based on the result of a projected function.